# Depend on OpenCV in Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, opencv2, libopencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With [this commit in rosdep key](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/88566973ff010fbfc7cf4208eefff9492e856b98#diff-acba1c75aeaa27ae4af7a5e0a5b78c08) that, now from `Hydro` there are at least 2 ROS ways to depend on `OpenCV`; via ROS 3rd package "[[OpenCV2]](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv2?distro=hydro)" or Ubuntu system dependency [libopencv-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libopencv-dev).

Should we update the all `package.xml` in Hydro that depend on OpenCV2 to replace with libopencv-dev?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173773/depend-on-opencv-in-hydro/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess it was just answered well on [Indigo Migration wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/indigo/Migration?action=diff&rev1=12&rev2=13).

```
The OpenCV packages are not built in the ROS ecosystem anymore, they rely on upstream packages. The rosdep keys are now: `libopencv-dev` and `python-opencv`

If your package supports Hydro and Indigo on one common branch, you want to depend on a common key that will pull in the right OpenCV for you (the ROS package on Hydro and the distribution package on Indigo). Hence, just depend on` cv_bridge` (which will also pull in `rosconsole` and `sensor_msgs)` or `image_geometry` (which will only pull in `sensor_msgs` but is harder to understand as a dependency, purpose-wise).
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0